# What is the point of making a subtype without specifying a range in Ada?

Tags: types, ada

In Ada, I have commonly seen something like this:

```
type Number is new Integer;
```

What is the point of this? Can't you just be happy with an `Integer`?
I have also seen code such as:

```
type Small_Number is range 1..5;
```

This makes sense to me; I can see why this would be useful. But why would you choose to use the former example?

Comment: Just to be clear about the terminology: Ada has a `renames` keyword that is used for renaming things (although it can't be used for types; the recommended way is to use `subtype`).  This gives a new name to something but doesn't create a new variable or type or whatever.  What you've described here is a *derived type* which is a totally different thing than a rename.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More commonly I have seen code like this:

```
Type Pounds  is new Integer;
Type Euros   is new Integer;
Type Dollars is new Integer;
```

This means that you are not going to assign your Pounds to Euros to Dollars by accident.

If you want to convert between the two you would need to either do an explicit cast, or write a conversion routine, both of which would take the applicable exchange rate into account.

(Now I think about it further, Float would have been better than Integer for this example!)

Comment: The binary number representation in floating point numbers ist often in conflict with the accountancy rules defined for decimal numbers. Using binary floats will occasionally make cents (dis)appear out of thin air. Fixed decimal numbers with e.g. 4 decimal digits are the type of choice here.

Answer (score 6):

The point is that `Number` is a *new* type, quite distinct from `Integer`.

That means more control over parameters and such since you cannot use an `Integer` where a `Number` is required; this aids with encapsulation.

It's quite plausible that you want to keep this level of control and perhaps plan for the future where you may end up with `Number` being totally different from `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that

```
type Number is new Integer;
```

(which is not a "renaming" of a type) looks like bad style, but there may be a perfectly good reason for it.  For example:

- You want `Number` to be a distinct type, but with the same range as `Integer`.
- You want `Number` to match the range of an array type with an `Integer` derived index.